# change an if / else if statement to a switch case in Arduino

Tags: server, arduino, arduino-esp32

I am making a web server with an ESP32D, I am programming it from the Arduino IDE and I have a function with spaghetti code which I want to refactor with switch case,
this is my function, which i am calling in the void loop()

```
void control(){
              if (header.indexOf("GET /2/on") >= 0) {
                Serial.println("GPIO 2 on");
                output2State = "on";
                digitalWrite(output2, HIGH);
              } else if (header.indexOf("GET /2/off") >= 0) {
                Serial.println("GPIO 2 off");
                output2State = "off";
                digitalWrite(output2, LOW);
              } else if (header.indexOf("GET /15/on") >= 0) {
                Serial.println("GPIO 15 on");
                output15State = "on";
                digitalWrite(output15, HIGH);
              } else if (header.indexOf("GET /15/off") >= 0) {
                Serial.println("GPIO 15 off");
                output15State = "off";
                digitalWrite(output15, LOW);
              }
} 




void function_loop(){
  
  WiFiClient client = server.available();   // Listen for incoming client
  // Serial.println(typeOf(client));

  

  if (client) {                             // If a new client connects,
    currentTime = millis();
    previousTime = currentTime;
    Serial.println("New Client.");          // print a message out in the serial port
    String currentLine = "";                // make a String to hold incoming data from the client
    while (client.connected() && currentTime - previousTime <= timeoutTime) {  // loop while the client's connected
      currentTime = millis();
      if (client.available()) {             // if there's bytes to read from the client,
        char c = client.read();             // read a byte, then
        Serial.write(c);                    // print it out the serial monitor
        header += c;
        if (c == '\n') {                    // if the byte is a newline character
          // if the current line is blank, you got two newline characters in a row.
          // that's the end of the client HTTP request, so send a response:
          if (currentLine.length() == 0) {
            // HTTP headers always start with a response code (e.g. HTTP/1.1 200 OK)
            // and a content-type so the client knows what's coming, then a blank line:
            client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
            client.println("Content-type:text/html");
            client.println("Connection: close");
            client.println(); 


            control();
            
}
```

How could I do to be able to pass it to switch case? I have no idea how to pass the variable to modify (in this case the header.indexOf)

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear from your example what type your `header` is, but I'm guessing it is a String.

Send `header` to control() like this

```
control(header);
```

and declare control() like this

```
void control(String& header) {
```

Comment: Yes. is a string I forget, before the void setup() I have declared:

`String header;`

Comment: I already made the changes you mention, but it keeps throwing me error:
`constantes.cpp:62:36: error: call to non-'constexpr' function 'int String::indexOf(const String&) const'
                 case header.indexOf("GET /2/on") >= 0:
                   `

Comment: this is my function now:

Comment: `void control(const String& header) {
  
                                                       switch (header){ case header.indexOf("GET /2/on") >= 0:               
                    Serial.println("GPIO 2 on");
                    output2State = "on";
                    digitalWrite(output2, HIGH);
                  break;

                case  header.indexOf("GET /2/off") >= 0:
                    Serial.println("GPIO 2 off");
                    output2State = "off";
                    digitalWrite(output2, LOW);
                    break;
        } }`

Comment: `switch (header)` won't work.  But you could search the index of `GET /2/` and `GET /15/` and `on` and `off` separately to "simplify".

Comment: @DanielMartinez I removed `const` from the declaration. Should work better